# "Use of undefined constant" notice, but the constant should be defined

Tags: php

there are three files: common.php, controller.php and user.php.

File common.php looks like:

```
<?php
define("MAXIMUM_NAME_LENGTH", 50);
?>
```

File controller.php looks like:

```
<?php
include("common.php");
include("user.php");
$user = new user();
?>
```

File user.php looks like:

```
<?php
class user{
private $var = MAXIMUM_NAME_LENGTH;
}
?>
```

When executing script there is given notice: Notice: Use of undefined constant MAXIMUM_NAME_LENGTH - assumed 'MAXIMUM_NAME_LENGTH' in /.../controller.php on line xxx. I want to share defined values in common.php between other files. How to do it in a proper way?

Comment: is your `user.php` file altering in any way the `MAXIMUM_NAME_LENGTH` var?

Comment: change your `include` to `require` to make sure your files are actually included correctly.  A quick test with PHP 5.2 confirms that this exact code should work.

Comment: try to replace `include` by `require` - maybe file is not included (wrong path).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you would have all defines included by the file that is going to use them.  IE: In your example, make the class file have a `$class->setMaxNameLength();` method and pass the name length define in through there, that way it won't throw you an error.

Comment: No, the PHP specs state that included files can use any constant that has already been defined.

Comment: And yet an include file twice down the chain (IE: If I include test1.php and test2.php from index.php in 5.3.7rc1, it doesn't let a variable defined in test1.php work in test2.php.

Comment: I'm not seeing that behavior.

Comment: Odd, must be specific to my combination of server / suhosin / php.ini configuration options.  :/

Answer (score 1):

Place `error_reporting(E_ALL);` the line before `include("common.php");`.

Most probably you'll see something like:

```
Warning: include(common.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in xxx
```

indicating that your three files are not in the same folder together, or together in a path that is not in your `include_path`, or a combination of that.

**EDIT:**

If you are using [Suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/), check your `suhosin.executor.include.*` settings.