# Use of Undefined Constant Althought Defined and Works Elsewhere OOP

Tags: php, oop

Im Building an MVC Structure Application in Php. Ive Created A Config Class that calls a config file with settings in an array so that I can choose what to set in an OOP way

example - **config_arrays.php** in **./root/application/config**

```
//Set System Url
$systemURL['devUrl'] = "http://localhost/Rush/";
$systemURL['liveUrl'] = 'http://www.relution-homes.com/';
```

example - **config-class.php** in **./root/system/core/**

```
function SetBaseUrl($systemURL) {
    if (Rf_Environment == 'Development') {
        define('Rf_URL', $systemURL['devUrl']);
    } elseif (Rf_Environment == 'Production') {
        define('Rf_URL', $systemURL['liveUrl']);
    } else {
        die('Please Set Application Environment in the Applications Root index File');
    }
}
```

**Usage** - to call the class takes place in the bootstrap folder I use spl_autoload_register after calling in the config_arrays then do this

```
// Create a new Instance of the Config Class
$Config = new Config();
// Set The Base Url
$Config->SetBaseUrl($systemURL);
```

And then heres where the fun starts . . .i use

```
 <?php echo Rf_Url; ?>
```

**in a page and it works fine try using it in a menu**

```
<li><a href="<?php echo Rf_Url;?>index">Home</a></li>
```

And I get 'USE OF UNDEFINED CONSTANT Rf_Url - Assumed Rf_URL

I have looked at

[What does the PHP error message "Notice: Use of undefined constant" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941169/what-does-the-php-error-message-notice-use-of-undefined-constant-mean)

And

["Use of undefined constant" notice, but the constant should be defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970368/use-of-undefined-constant-notice-but-the-constant-should-be-defined)

With No definite answers . . .I've tried Double Quoting Everything Single Quoting Did think I could use isset() but then realized that this may not be beneficial in the long run.

Comment: Is your `config-class.php` included/required in the page you are trying to access this constant?

Comment: No I use spl autoload register before any of the above happens it searches for the class based on the name and automatically calls it when required ie when i use $config = new config(); it calls the class

Comment: PHP is lettercase dependant for constants. You example php does: define('Rf_URL',... your echo does: echo Rf_Url; and the warning: Assumed Rf_URL... makes sense in that it found a constant with a similar name and used it.